# MENU HAMBURGUESA NO CIERRA!

Tags: javascript, html5

Soy principiante!! hice con tutorial una pagina pero el menu hambubrguesa algo le hice mal!! abre, slecciona el link pero no se cierra!! solo cierra si toco el tache, pero de otra forma no cierra!! anexo los codigos a ver si me pueden echar la mano!! de antemano mil gracias!!

```
<header class="hero">
<nav class="nav container">
    <div id="#regresa" class="nav__logo">
        <h1>VacaDivertido!</h1>
        <h2 class="nav__title">Agencia de viajes</h2>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav__link nav__link--menu">
        <li class="nav__items">
            <a href="#inicio" class="nav__links">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__items">
            <a href="#contacta" class="nav__links">Contacta</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__items">
            <a href="#testimonios" class="nav__links">Testimonios</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__items">
            <a href="#blog" class="nav__links">Blog</a>
        </li>

        <img src="/Icon/close.svg" class="nav__close">
    </ul>

    <div class="nav__menu">
        <img src="/Icon/menu.svg" class="nav__img">
    </div>
</nav>
```

Mi codigo de javascript es

```
(function(){
const openButton = document.querySelector('.nav__menu');
const menu = document.querySelector('.nav__link');
const closeMenu = document.querySelector('.nav__close');

openButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    menu.classList.add('nav__link--show');
});

closeMenu.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    menu.classList.remove('nav__link--show');
});

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser el selector id que le pusiste en el HTML. Yo le sacaría el "#".

```
    <div id="#regresa" class="nav__logo">
        <h1>VacaDivertido!</h1>
        <h2 class="nav__title">Agencia de viajes</h2>
    </div>
```

Si solo eso no te funciona, hacé una función para que cierre cuando hagas clic en algún enlace, sería algo así:

```
    menu.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
            menu.classList.remove('nav__link--show');
        }
    });
```

Espero que te sirva. Me avisas si soluciona tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! quedo de lujo!!!!